# Why is angular.io using old version of Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular

If I read the source of https://angular.io/ right, it looks to me that they are still using Angular 1 there i.e. 1.6 version. To me it is a hint that while the new version of Angular is very advanced there are still challenges when it comes to production deployments of sites that are publicly available?

Answer (score 1):

Story of the undeveloped chicken and the egg. angular.io was there when the new angular was still in alpha. You cannot safely use an alpha version in production builds. Now that angular is released, there is no real advantage in refactoring the entire site to use the new version. Why break something that ain't broken.

If you check the [material site](https://material.angular.io/) you will see that it is build in the new angular

Comment: The chicken  and egg argument is convincing but given Angular 4 is being released surely they should migrate angular.io onto at least Angular 2. Correct me if I am wrong but the whole purpose of angular.io is to promote the new Angular i.e. >= 2 while angularjs.org is supposed to serve the old framework. I do not think it is a good idea to promote Angular 2 site while having it built in Angular 1, it is not the way to win your users confidence.

Comment: If you have a limited number of resources, why would you spend time doing a rewardless rewrite of the documentation page, versus spending time improving the framework.

Comment: Resource argument can be used to justify any deficiency.

Comment: @coolfeature read about angular 4 and angular 2. They've changed to SEMVER versioning, which means that a new major number, just means some breaking changes. They rather not talk about angular 2 or 4 or what number anymore. It's just 'angular'.

Answer (score 0):

Angular.io using Angular 1 instead of 2 becouse they created this page during working on angular 2 when it wasn't ready yet to production.

Comment: Angular 4 being released surely you would expect angular.io to be on Angular 2 by now?

Comment: the difference between Angular 1 and Angular 2 is not the same as between the Angular 2.x.x and Anglar 4.x.x.

Comment: I am well aware of that and that is what I argue, angular.io which showcases 'Angular' (>=2)  should be implemented in 'Angular' as opposed to 'angularjs' (1.x).

Comment: @coolfeature, This don't have to be the case, although it would be better if it do. Like we can use java to build the compiler of scala.